# Win10 laptop cant connect to a public network (mcdonalds) that Ive been using for months

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, connection

Being homeless, I rely on McDonalds for power/internet to use my laptop, and ive been coming here using it for months now. But yesterday all of a sudden I stopped being able to connect to the network completely, when I try and connect it just tells me "Cant connect to this network". I cant use the network troubleshooter cause I cant connect at all in the first place. I wasnt doing anything unusual when the problem started, no hardware/software/driver changes of any kind.

Ive tried googling the problem myself, but in everything I can find, people are able to connect to the network, but not the internet, whereas I cant connect to the network itself.

My phone can connect to the network, and my laptop can connect to other networks, so its specifically my laptop with this one network.

Ive tried swapping between IP4 and IP6; Ive tried changing my MAC address

I have no idea what else to try and Im really hoping someone can help cause Im currently burning through my very limited hotspot data trying to figure this out :(

EDIT: Tried a TCP/IP Reset /DNS Flush, didnt help any.
Tried a network reset, didnt work.
Theres no updates available for my drivers, already checked.

Final edit: So I honestly have no idea why cause nothing I tried worked, but it just randomly decided to start working again. Thanks for all the help even if it didnt actually help :)

Comment: I am not certain about this, but one thing I would try is a TCP/IP Reset /DNS Flush. This does not require internet to do and the two things might help.   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer  (be sure to restart)

Comment: @john Just tried that, it didnt help any.

Comment: I am will keep looking. I am not sure what you can do without extensive Internet.

Comment: If you can find a place where you can connect, you might try updating the Wireless Driver to see if that helps.

Comment: @John that was one of the first things I tried. Im currently connecting via my phones hotspot, but thats a very temporary solution as I only get 10gb of hotspot a month.

Comment: its possible they blocked your laptop

Comment: You sure have a lot of skills.  You should try finding a job in this industry :)

Comment: @Keltari is there anyway around it if they did? I already tried changing my mac address and that usually gets around any IP-based blocks, but I dont know if there are any other ways to block a computer on a public network

Comment: You could try buying a USB WiFi dongle and see if that works. The other thing to try is to connect your phone to your laptop using a USB cable then activate USB tethering while you phone is connected to the WiFi. This usually works for tethering WiFi networks to USB at least on Android phones.

Comment: Have you tried to use the "forget network" option?

Comment: @Aenfa My USB tether option is grayed out on my phone, so cant try that :(

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah I tried that

Comment: What optional Windows Updates have recently been installed?

Comment: You need to connect it to the laptop for the USB tether option to be available.

Comment: @Aenfa - User want's to fix their WiFi issue and NOT use their phone as a tether.

Comment: Have you tried a different McDonald's? Maybe they have a leech limit?? Or maybe figure out how to change your MAC address.

Comment: @Ramhound The only recent update was to my graphics card and that was a couple weeks ago.

Comment: @Tetsujin Havent tried a different McDonalds, but as stated in my op Ive already tried changing my MAC address.

Comment: The reason I am asking about the driver, is what you describe sounds like a driver issue, which could have been caused by a driver configuration change.  It doesn't sound like you are banned from the network, especially since, it doesn't work at another location (which would nearly be impossible to be synchronized).

Comment: Try to connect to another completely different Wifi hotstop, that would allow to clearly see if you have an hardware problem or just a problem with a specific Wifi network. I bet on the second case. As you seem quite knowledgeable you can also try to boot from a linux USB key and see what happens there (I believe you have far better troubleshooting tools in that environment but it needs practice of course)

Comment: So... I have absolutely no idea why, but it just randomly started working again. Its really weird. Well thanks for all the advice anyway guys!

Comment: I've closed this because it seems that it might have been some transient network issue. It was a well asked question and people tried to help, but sometimes odd things just happen.